# Compare 2 FILES and print line number for non-matching record and column number for each non-matching records in TEST2.txt

Tags: text-processing, awk, files

In TEST1.txt

```
ID_ID   First_name    Last_name   Address                        Contact_Number
ID1     John          Rock        32, Park Lake, California           2222200000
ID2     Tommy         Hill    5322 Otter Lane Middleberge         3333300000
ID3     Leonardo      Test        Half-Way Pond, Georgetown           4444400000
ID8     Rhyan         Bigsh       6762,33 Ave N,St. Petersburg        5555500000
ID50    Steve         Goldberg    6762,33 Ave N,St. Petersburg        6666600000
```

&&

In TEST2.txt

```
ID_ID   First_name    Last_name   Address                        Contact_Number
ID1     John          Rock        32, Park Lake, California           2222200000
ID2     Tommy1        Hill1       5322 Otter Lane Middleberge         3333300000
ID3     Leonardo      Test        Half-Way Pond, Georgetown           4444400000
ID80    Sylvester     Stallone                                    5555500000
ID50    Steve         Goldberg    6762,33 Ave N,St. Petersburg    6666600000
ID60    Mark          Waugh       St. Petersburg                  7777700000
```

Desired Result:-

Difference in TEST2.txt is line number and  column number (where the values do not match)

```
Line No. 2 COLUMN NO 2,3    
Line No. 4 COLUNN NO 1,2,3,4 
Line No. 6 COLUNN NO 1,2,3,4,5
```

Note: File size to be compare is in GB and File is tab separated and has more than 250 tab separated column.

Comment: awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0]++; next} !a[$0]{print FNR}' TEST1.txt TEST2.txt.

Comment: Do all lines exist in both files and are they sorted the same? Or are lines missing in either file and should be noted as `Line no. X COLUMN NO 1,2,...,N` (i.e. all fields differ)?

Comment: Both the files will be sorted. All the lines will be present, however only the column values may differ.

Answer (score 0):

Clumsy but working:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="\t"
}

NR==FNR {
# 5 = number of columns
    for (i=0;i<=5;i++) {
        a[$1,i]=$i }
    }

{ if ( a[$1,0] != $0 ) {
    b=""
    for (i=1;i<=5;i++) {
        if ( a[$1,i] != $i ) {
            b=b i", "
            }
        }
    print "Line No." FNR," Column No. ",b
    }
}
```

I would however strongly suggest you write a (e.g.) FORTRAN program for this as you then could read in the data in chunks of - say - 10,000 lines while `awk`-solutions need to hold at least one file in the RAM which might be aproblem for your GB-sized files. It could look like this:

- read blocks of data from each file into array (line & column)
- compare arrays and create logical array with result of a(i,j)=b(i,j)
- us logical array to create output
- print output and read next block

Since your files are sorted and have all lines present, it's fairly simple.